# How do I get a list of values?

Tags: filemaker

I have a table `Targets` with unique ID `number` and field `data`. I want to get a list containing all values of `number` in `Targets` so this list (preferably comma separated) can end up as a JS array in a Web View.

In SQL, it would be as simple as

```
SELECT number FROM Targets
```

But I can't find any reasonable method in FileMaker Pro Advanced 11. I think the `List` function may be it, but for some reason, it won't list all my rows.

Bonus points if you can do the equivalent of

```
SELECT number, data FROM Targets
```

Comment: A good answer to your question will vary based on how you're trying to use the data that you are gathering. How are you presenting it to the user? By putting it in a field? As a drop-down menu? As an export?

Answer (score 1):

On the **Targets** table, add a calculation field (say, **ID Data Array**) that looks like a javascript array literal:

```
"[" & number & "," & data & "]"
```

On a layout that has a cross-product relationship to a **Targets** table occurrence (say, **Targets All**), add a Web View component with something like the following calculated content:

```
"data:text/html,¶" &
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " & Quote ( "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" ) & "¶" &
Quote ( "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" ) & ">¶" &
"<html xmlns=" & Quote ( "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ) & ">¶" &
"<head>¶" &
"<meta http-equiv=" & Quote ( "content-type" ) & " content=" & Quote ( "text/html; charset=utf-8" ) & " />¶" &
"<title>Table Data</title>¶" &
"<script type=" & Quote ( "text/javascript" ) & " src=" & Quote ( "script.js" ) & " ) & ">¶" &
"var dataArray = [ " & Substitute ( List ( Targets All::ID Data Array ) ; "¶" ; "," ) & "];¶" &
"</script>¶" &
"</head>¶" &
"<body>¶" &

"</body>¶" &
"</html>"
```

The key component is this:

```
"var dataArray = [ " & Substitute ( List ( Targets All::ID Data Array ) ; "¶" ; "," ) & "];¶"
```

This uses the **List** function to collate all the related **ID Data Array** fields into one ¶-delimited list.

It then uses the **Substitute** function to replace the ¶ characters with commas so you get a nice comma-delimited list of arrays.

Finally, it wraps it in a javascript variable declaration so you will have the variable **dataArray** available in the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in FileMaker Pro 11, use one of the SQL plugins to query itself. Or, upgrade to v12 and use the new SQL command.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations of which SQL plugin to use?

Comment: SmartPill allows access to SQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, which may seem like a hack but is not, is to make a valuelist.  Make a valuelist set to display all values in "number".  FileMaker will automatically consolidate all values into a return-separated list of unique values.  Then you can get the list by running the calculation:

```
 ValueListItems( Get(FileName) ; "AND-PUT-YOUR-VALUELIST-NAME-HERE")
```